# Check the content of a div with PrototypeJS

Tags: prototypejs

I use PrototypeJS and I need to check whether the content of a `div` is null or not. But the followng code gives an error. The `div` does not initially exist. It is added via an AJAX function. How can I check it?

```
if($('lesson-'+tab).innerHTML() == null)
  {
     //do the job
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a string property of the HTMLElement, and not a `function` so you will get an error when calling it. As it is a string, you do not check for null but for the string being empty.
Additionally you might want to check, whether the element exists in order to prevent an error when result of the `$` function is `null`.
And, as John Conde already mentioned, you need to check after the AJAX call is done:

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
  onComplete: function(transport) {
    var lessonTab = $('lesson-' + tab)
    if (!lessonTab || lessonTab.innerHTML.length === 0) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait until after the Ajax call to check the contents of that DIV:

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
    if($('lesson-'+tab).innerHTML() == null)
    {
     //do the job
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: this code contains errors. `if($('lesson-'+tab).innerHTML() == null` will always fail regardeless of context, but you make a good point.